# Selenium wait.until to check ajax request finished is throw error

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait

in selenium Webdriver with Python, i want to wait for an Ajax request to completed(jquery library). i use wait.until() function of Selenium. Ajax request is start after click on submitJquery button.

```
wait.until(self.driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
```

but i got following error:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_MahsumAkbasNet_Pass (__main__.TestClass)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\xxx\src\unittestpackage\JavaScriptExec.py", line 24, in test_MahsumAkbasNet_Pass
    wait.until(self.driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 66, in until
    value = method(self._driver)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 14.449s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

complete code is:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import unittest
import time
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_MahsumAkbasNet_Pass(self):
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)

        self.driver.get("http://www.mahsumakbas.net/selenium")

        self.driver.find_element_by_id("submitJquery").click()     

        wait.until(self.driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))

        print "Jquery is completed"

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to pass a *callable* to `wait.until()`:

```
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
```

Comment: if you are getting `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` that might be because the jQuery is not loaded while you run this line.